# hierarchical query to return final row

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have a hierarchical query that doesn't return an expected row (employee badge = 444).

TABLE: hr_data

```
badge fname supervisor_badge
111   Jeff  222
222   Joe   333
333   John  444
444   Tom   444
```

SQL:

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE As IC, 
       badge, 
       fname, 
       supervisor_badge
  FROM hr_data 
START WITH badge = '111' 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE badge = PRIOR supervisor_badge
```

What is Returned:

```
IC badge fname supervisor_badge
0 111   Jeff  222
0 222   Joe   333
1 333   John  444
```

What is Expected:

```
IC badge fname supervisor_badge
0 111   Jeff  222
0 222   Joe   333
**0** 333   John  444
**1** 444   Tom   444
```

How can I get this query to return the employee `Tom` and then stop?

Answer (score 0):

Remove NOCYCLE clause from your query:

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE As IC, 
       badge, 
       fname, 
       supervisor_badge
  FROM hr_data 
START WITH badge = '111' 
CONNECT BY badge = PRIOR supervisor_badge
```

Comment: Thanks but that returns java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data

Comment: I'm not familiar with this feature, but can you do something like this?  `CONNECT BY PRIOR badge != PRIOR supervisor_badge AND badge = PRIOR supervisor_badge`.  Also, according to this page (http://www.rampant-books.com/10g_79.htm), you cannot use CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE without the NOCYCLE clause, but in this case I think you can replace your use of CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE with a check for `(badge = supervisor_badge)`

Comment: Thanks DWA.  That works! Unfortunately your correct answer is only a comment.

Comment: Glad to hear that worked.  I'm just building off of Cybernate's answer, so I don't consider it to really be my answer.  I am concerned, though, that you've potentially your protection against actual loops in your data:  I.e. what if John's supervisor_badge was accidentally changed to '111'?  I'm not sure if you were intending to handle those types of situations with your original use of the NOCYCLE clause.

Comment: I still use the NOCYCLE clause.  What worked at grabbing the last missing employee Tom was your suggesting using "PRIOR badge != PRIOR supervisor_badge" along with my original CONNECT BY "PRIOR supervisor_badge = badge".  Using PRIOR on both sides of a NOT (!=) for a CONNECT BY is a little hard to follow for the CONNECT, but all I care about is that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the opposite approach and descending the tree gives you the desired result, but haven't got your approach working just yet.  Here is the opposite:

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE As IC, 
       badge, 
       fname, 
       supervisor_badge
  FROM (select '111' badge, 'Jeff' fname, '222' supervisor_badge from dual union all
        select '222' badge, 'Joe' fname, '333' supervisor_badge from dual union all
        select '333' badge, 'John' fname, '444' supervisor_badge from dual union all
        select '444' badge, 'Tom' fname, '444' supervisor_badge from dual
       ) 
START WITH badge = '444' 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR badge = supervisor_badge;
```

Produces:

```
 IC BADGE FNAME      SUPERVISOR_BADGE
--- ----- ---------- ------------------
  1 444   Tom        444
  0 333   John       444
  0 222   Joe        333
  0 111   Jeff       222
```

Comment: My data was conceptual and there are really about 10,000 employees in the database.  I don't understand why I would want to use subqueries in the FROM clause or in other words I don't understand what you are trying to convey in your answer.

Comment: @jeff: The subquery is with the union all's is just so I have some sample data to run the query against.  For you it would just be your source table.